# Programmatically set NSTextField action

Tags: cocoa, swift3, nstextfield

I've having an issue receiving up the actions from an NSTextField. In my app, I have some NSTextFields created via interface builder, while others are created programmatically.

It appears that by default, the IB textfields send an action on end editing. But if I create a NSTextField by using the `init(frame:)` initializer, it only sends an action on enter.

I realize I can "solve" this by subclassing and overriding the `controlTextDidEndEditing` function and then sending an action there, but when I call `super.controlTextDidEndEditing` it also sends an action. So the action is then sent twice... I really just want my text fields created via code to use the option "Sent on end editing".

Is there not a way to change this interface builder setting via code?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set it in code. It is actually a property on the text field's cell:

```
// Same as IB's “Sent On End Editing”.
myTextField.cell?.sendsActionOnEndEditing = true

// Same as IB's “Send on Enter Only”.
myTextField.cell?.sendsActionOnEndEditing = false
```

Comment: Didn't realize that it's part of the cell and not the NSTextField. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why it is buried there when it is available as an option of textfield in IB